AWS Load Balancer Controller can't deploy ELB
I'm having issues with setting up AWS Load Balancer Controller (AWS LBC) on an EKS located within a private VPC (no internet access, just intranet to my corp network).
I provided all endpoints that I could find related to AWS LBC so the internet connectivity is not an issue (ec2, sts, ecr, eks-auth, elasticloadbalancing, execute-api - I know I kind of run out of ideas).
Intranet subnets have been tagged with the required tags for internal load balancers to be deployed in them.
The deployment (via helm release) of AWS LBC is successful and the deployment together with the pods seem healthy.
When trying to provision an application deployment and service is when issues arise. The AWS LBC logs say that it doesn't have enough permissions to create the required load balancer.
Logs from running kubectl describe svc ilz-lbc -n ilz-lbc:
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From     Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----     -------
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  2s (x7 over 21s)  service  Failed build model due to NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
           For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

Log entry from running kubectl logs -n kube-system deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller:
{"level":"error","ts":"2024-07-22T14:15:16Z","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"service","namespace":"ilz-lbc","name":"ilz-lbc","reconcileID":"75bcf751-f69d-4503-9850-6170a6321e9e","error":"NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors"}

There are multiple such error logs, obviously besides the healthy info logs that display right after provisioning AWS LBC.
We have used Amazon EKS Pod Identity Agent for assigning IAM roles to Kubernetes service accounts (specifically aws-load-balancer-controller serviceaccount from namespace kube-system).
Here you can see the pod identity association:
pod identity association
Below you can find the policy used in the associated iam role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
                "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTrustStores"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DeleteProtection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "elasticloadbalancing:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateTargetGroup",
                        "CreateLoadBalancer"
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Tried adding the iam role to the nodes as well but it didn't work neither.
EDIT:
I got it working (not sure why)
Changed the service.yaml file from
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilz
  namespace: ilz
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ilz

to
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilz
  namespace: ilz
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ilz

As you can see, the only things that have changed are the annotations. I'm not sure why it works with this annotation. My version of AWS LBC seems to be the latest available:
❯ helm list -n kube-system
NAME                            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                         STATUS  CHART                                   APP VERSION
aws-load-balancer-controller    kube-system     1               2024-07-22 13:29:33.362051131 +0300 EEST        deployedaws-load-balancer-controller-1.8.1      v2.8.1

However, the official AWS LBC documentation doesn't specify no such annotation: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.8/guide/ingress/annotations/
Is the documentation out of date?
I tried this annotation while inspecting the official kubernetes service documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer (AWS Section)
Could you please elaborate on why is this the case?

Solution: set hop limit >= 2 as the documentation suggests: aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options --http-put-response-hop-limit 2 --http-tokens required --region <region> --instance-id <instance-id>
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.8/deploy/installation/#using-the-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-server-version-2-imdsv2
